# changeset begin/end methods in DPC_EXT but GCS_METHODS-CHANGESET_BEGIN unknown

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap

My SAPui5 web app throws this error in Chrome's console:

```
The following problem occurred: HTTP request failed500,Internal Server Error,{"error":{
"code":"/IWBEP/CM_MGW_RT/053","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Default changeset impleme
ntation allows only one operation"},"innererror":{"application":{"component_id":"CA","s
ervice_namespace":"/SAP/","service_id":"YFLEXUI_LEAVE_REQUEST_SRV","service_version":"0
001"},"transactionid":"something","timestamp":"something","Error_Resolution":{"SAP_Tran
saction":"For backend administrators: run transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG on SAP Gateway h
ub system and search for entries with the timestamp above for more details","SAP_Note":
"See SAP Note 1797736 for error analysis (https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/179
7736)"},"errordetails":[{"code":"/IWBEP/CX_MGW_TECH_EXCEPTION","message":"Default chang
eset implementation allows only one operation","propertyref":"","severity":"error","tar
get":""}]}}} -
```

According to some posts on the internet, the problem is caused by the conflict between these methods:

```
/iwbep/if_mgw_appl_srv_runtime~changeset_begin
/iwbep/if_mgw_appl_srv_runtime~changeset_end
```

and

```
/iwbep/if_mgw_core_srv_runtime~changeset_begin
/iwbep/if_mgw_core_srv_runtime~changeset_end
```

Most people advice to redefine the methods `/iwbep/if_mgw_appl_srv_runtime~changeset_begin` and `/iwbep/if_mgw_appl_srv_runtime~changeset_end`.

This is my `/iwbep/if_mgw_appl_srv_runtime~changeset_begin` method:

```
METHOD /iwbep/if_mgw_appl_srv_runtime~changeset_begin.
* Default Implementation:
*  - Local Update Task
*  - Only one operation in each changeset
*  - No deferred processing: Immediate process changset operation

    SET UPDATE TASK LOCAL.

    IF lines( it_operation_info ) > 1.
      RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE /iwbep/cx_mgw_tech_exception
        EXPORTING
          textid = /iwbep/cx_mgw_tech_exception=>changeset_default_violation
          method = gcs_methods-changeset_begin.
    ENDIF.

    CLEAR cv_defer_mode.
ENDMETHOD.
```

The problem is, in SE80, after the redefinition of `/iwbep/if_mgw_appl_srv_runtime~changeset_begin` when I try to check that method and activate it, SAP throws this error:

> Field GCS_METHODS-CHANGESET_BEGIN is unknown

Can you tell me how can `/iwbep/if_mgw_appl_srv_runtime~changeset_begin`'s redefinition cause such error?

FYI. `gcs_methods` is a private constant. It might be causing the problem.

Comment: You know that a subclass cannot use a **private** member of its superclass (unless the superclass said the subclass is its friend). Was it the question?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Okay, I turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subclass cannot use a **private** member of its superclass (unless the superclass said the subclass is its friend).

As the superclass is generated, you have to duplicate the constant in your own program.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue recently and redefined the method like this:

```
METHOD /iwbep/if_mgw_core_srv_runtime~changeset_begin.

  IF line_exists( it_operation_info[ entity_type = 'ENTITY_TYPE' ] ).
    cv_defer_mode = abap_true.
  ENDIF.

ENDMETHOD
```

I'm no expert on this topic, but this implementation fixed our problem.
What the issue with your private constant is, however, I cannot tell.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the inactive methods on the class interface. A simple code check tells all the erros of this implementation.

BR,